# chatbox widget in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

any chatbox or chat widget or add-on that can be added on my web page? using C#.NET....

Thanks,
Nhoyti

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at these websites...
All of these are AJAX based :)

https://blueimp.net/ajax/

http://ajaxim.com/

http://sourceforge.net/projects/ajax-chat/

http://socket7.net/page/lace

http://www.aspnetajaxchat.com/overview.html

http://www.vista-files.org/programs/estream/asp-net-ajax-chat.html

OK, ill be honest, these were top results for a Google search of "AJAX Chat" and "Free AJAX Chat"

If you just want to get away by integrating a chat application to your site, use simply a pre-built chat widget

If you want to know how to make a chat application for the fun of it or whatever reason, take a look @ this page

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/coding4fun/archive/2007/03/01/1785048.aspx